# How to access $preexec_functions from a script

Tags: zsh

I'm converting some Zsh functions to run as scripts, and in one of them I need to access values in (for example) `$preexec_functions`.  Everything works perfectly in the functions, but this fails in the script.

Is it possible to access this value from a script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If that code is meant to access internal data of your interactive shell, they shouldn't run as separate programs (scripts), but should be interpreted by that shell, so either as functions, autoloaded functions or *sourced* scripts.

If the reason why you want them defined as scripts is that you don't want them to pollute the environment of your shell, you can run them in subshells. Use:

```
myfunction() (
  ...
)
```

Instead of:

```
myfunction() {
  ...
}
```

If it's because you don't want their definition added to your `~/.zshrc`, add them to another file and source that file from your `~/.zshrc` (`source /path/to/that/file`), or use autoloadable functions.

If you still want to have those run as scripts/separate programs, you'd need to pass the definition of those functions and everything else the script might need some way or another. Like:

```
CODE=$(
  typeset -p preexec_functions
  (($#preexec_functions)) && functions $preexec_functions
) your-script
```

And have `your-script` do:

```
eval "$CODE"
```

That is dump the definition of that array and all the functions it references as shell code and have that code interpreted by the script to that the same array and functions be declared there.